# Parsing JSON data in a table

Tags: java, android, json

```
`JSONObject c;JSONArray events;JSONObject event_data;
        JSONArray cont;JSONObject contacts_data;
        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(data);
        categories = jsonObj.getJSONArray("categories");
        for (i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++)
        {
            ContentValues valuesCat=new ContentValues();
            c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = c.getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String blck=c.getString("black_icon_url");
            String wht=c.getString("white_icon_url");
            valuesCat.put(GetData.CATEGORY_ID, "c_"+(i+1) );
            valuesCat.put(GetData.C_NAME, name);
            valuesCat.put(GetData.BLACK, blck);
            valuesCat.put(GetData.WHITE, wht);
            try{
            db.insertOrThrow(GetData.TABLE_CATEGORTIES, null, valuesCat);}
            catch(Exception e){}
            events=c.getJSONArray("events") ;
            for(j = 0 ; j < events.length() ; j++)
            {
                event_data = events.getJSONObject(j);
                cont=event_data.getJSONArray("contacts");
                for(k = 0 ; k < cont.length() ; k++)
                {
                    ContentValues valuesCon=new ContentValues();
                    contacts_data=cont.getJSONObject(k);
                    String nm1=contacts_data.getString("name");
                    String phone=contacts_data.getString("phone");
                    String fb=contacts_data.getString("facebook");
                    String id="c_"+(i+1)+"e_"+(j+1)+"_"+k;
                    valuesCon.put(GetData.CONTACT_ID, id);
                    valuesCon.put(GetData.NAME, nm1);
                    valuesCon.put(GetData.PHONE, phone);
                    valuesCon.put(GetData.FAB, fb);
                    db.insertOrThrow(GetData.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, valuesCon);

                }

            }
        }           
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

JSON [link]:"http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.edg.co.in/events.json"

I am parsing the following JSON object into a table but when i run my code only the first iteration runs successfully and the loop is terminated . The JSON i am dealing with is a bit complex  it has array inside another array and another array . HELP!! to iterate over the entire JSON object

Comment: I would bet there is an `Exception` being thrown. What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: datas do gt inserted for i=0 ,j=0,k=0 after then blank. Is there any problem with the loop ?

Comment: `categories.length()` might be 1...

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use the GSON Librarie, i've been dealing with it for few months and it is really powerfull.

What you need to do is to define you data models and the GSON librarie will do the rest for you, it will allocate everything as needed, it will fill your information into your objects ...

download => https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

some examples => https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide